# How can I solve the following equation for $x , y$.

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, cubics

We're given the following restrictions: 
$$x < y$$

$$-29x^3+15y^3=-61209$$

and

$$-60x-90y=-3420$$

Using these three things, we need to find the value of:

$$-50x^2+70y^2$$

Is there a simple approach to solve this? Solving both equations for $x$ and $y$ and plugging in the required result, makes things very complicated and I'm hoping that there is an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Solve for, say, y in terms of x, in the second equation.  Then substitute (plug in) the $y$ you solved for into $y$ in the first equation.  You'll then have a cubic in one variable.  E.g., $90y= -60 x + 3420 \implies 9y= 342-6x \implies y=38-\frac 23x$

Comment: @amWhy Yes thats what i tried, is their any other approach to this? Like applying x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy) to the first equation? Will their be any benefit  from that?

Comment: check for integers first, you might get lucky.  Often contest give questions that would be very difficult, except that there is a solution that is easy enough to guess, then fairly easy to confirm. For integer coefficient equations, that would be integer values for the variables.  In comparison: it is hard to factor a large integer, but it is easy to confirm a given factorization byt multiplying the proposed factors together

Answer (score 3):

We need to solve the following system.
$$29x^3-15y^3=61209$$ and $$2x+3y=114,$$ which gives
$$29x^3-15y^3=\frac{61209(2x+3y)^3}{114^3}$$ or
$$54872(29x^3-15y^3)=2267(2x+3y)^3$$ or
$$524384x^3-27204x^2y-40806xy^2-294763y^3=0$$ or
$$524384x^3-458836x^2y+431632x^2y-377678xy^2+336872xy^2-294763y^3=0$$ or
$$65548x^2(8x-7y)+53954xy(8x-7y)+42109y^2(8x-7y)=0$$ or
$$(8x-7y)(65548x^2+53954xy+42109y^2)=0,$$ which gives $$8x-7y=0$$ and the rest is smooth.

We can get a factor $8x-7y$ by the following way.
$$524384=2^5\cdot7\cdot2341$$ and
$$294763=7\cdot17\cdot2477.$$
Now, if there is a factor $ax+by$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers,

so $a$ divides $2^5\cdot7\cdot2341$ and $b$ divides $7\cdot17\cdot2477.$

We see that $a=8$ and $b=-7$ are valid.

Comment: Very nice :) ${}$

Comment: @Ravi S Ranjan I fixed the typo and explained a factorization. See now.

Comment: @Ravi S Ranjan See please better my post. I showed it.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg  In the 5th , 6th line of your solution, How did you convert/split  -27204x^2y   to  -458836x^2y  , +431632x^2y . 
  And 40806xy^2 to -377678xy^2 ,  +336872xy^2 ?????????

Comment: @Ravi S Ranjan Because $431632-458836=-27204$ and the second is similar.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg  But -38000 + 10796 = -27204 too. Infinities values can sum to -27204.

Comment: @Ravi S Ranjan Firstly I got the factor $8x-7y$ and after this I made factoring.

Comment: May i know how you got the factor 8x-7y . Thats what my whole point of the question is. I am trying to program this question (Having similar 30-40 questions , just coefficients  change) in python and just get the factor term. i.e, 8x-7y. If you can let me know how you got that, it will be a charm.

Comment: @Ravi S Ranjan I added something. See now.